# GEGL Library Installation on Windows

Tags: image-processing, gnome, gimp, gegl

I am new in image processing field, and I want to use GEGL to try things on Windows, I clone these libraries from Gnome:

1. gegl.
2. babl.
3. glib.

When I opened the examples in GEGLE "hello-world.c", I get an error

> Cannot open source file "glibconfig.h" (dependency of "gegl.h")

Can anyone help me to build GEGL on Windows in steps?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fNLj.png)

Comment: any help please or from where should start?